# jQuery: Fading CSS hover on top of static button?

Tags: jquery, css, button, navigation

I am creating a navigation and have already made the CSS properties for the buttons.

I would like to fade in the hover properties on top of the static button properties.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

the CSS looks like this:

```
<div id="nav">
    <form method="post" action="">
        <a>Home</a>
        <a>Link2</a>
        <a>Link3</a>
    </form>
</div>

#nav {
position:absolute;
margin-top:96px;
margin-left:30px;
height: 450px;
width: 140px;
font-family:"Book Antiqua";}

#nav a {
background:url(Images/Button.png);
height:28px;
width:130px;
font-family:"Book Antiqua";
font-size:14px;
text-align:center;
color:#C60;
text-decoration:none;
background-position:center;
margin:auto;
display:block;
position:relative;
line-height:190%;
}

#nav a:hover {
background:url(Images/Button%20Hover.png);
height:34px;
width:140px;
font-family:"Book Antiqua";
font-size:16px;
text-align:center;
color:#C60;
text-decoration:none;
margin:-3px;
z-index:2;
line-height:210%;
text-indent:-10px;}

#nav a:active {
background:url(Images/Button%20Hover.png);
height:34px;
width:140px;
font-family:"Book Antiqua";
font-size:14px;
text-align:center;
color:#862902;
text-decoration:none;
margin:0 -3px;
z-index:2;}
```

Thanks.

Comment: one thing that isn't really related to the hover question is that you can streamline your css quite a bit.   any of the nav properties that don't change (i.e. font-family).  Just set those in your #nav block and don't reset them downline unless you want it to change.   makes it much easier if you want to change that property later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transition` property of css...

```
-webkit-transition:all .3s;
-moz-transition:all .3s;
-o-transition:all .3s;
-ms-transition:all .3s;
```

Add this in `#nav a`...

This works with Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Opera and latest IE...

Comment: this is great however because the navigation is vertical and the buttons move down a bit as it is animating.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with jQuery then, give you're hover states a class as well.. like this:

```
#nav a:hover, #nav a.j-hover { .... }
```

Now use the [toggleClass](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/toggleClass) function with `hover` in jQuery like this:

```
$('#nav a').hover(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("js-hover", 1000);
});
```